# Workflow: Send notification action does not fire when new item is added

Tags: workflow, send-email

I have a workflow setup to send an email when a condition is met. I also have the box checked to initiate workflow when a new item is added.
Issue: I have a sharepoint group as recipient on the "Send Email" action. On adding a new item to the list, Workflow gets initiated but does not execute the Send Email action when I end execution and initiate manually then it sends email. Not sure if this is a permission issue because it only occurs when another user adds a new item.
I have set the group access to contribute. 
I also tried individually adding recipients instead of the group and it worked. But my workflow has multiple notifications depending on the a field "Status" (for instance- Choice1, Choice2, Choice3) and around 40 users in group so managing individual users every time would not be ideal.

Can somebody please help with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

a. Make sure the group is a SharePoint group and not a AD group

b. Verify Group Settings area, under Who can view the membership of the group, Everyone is selected.

c. Try to wrap the workflow in app step.